# python os.chmod not working inside a container

Tags: python, docker, permissions, containers, chmod

I have a container running with `sudo docker run -it --rm --name my-test-env python:3.8`. With the `-it` flag I have access directly to test my code. When I run:

```
import os
local_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "tmp", "my_folder")
os.makedirs(local_path, exist_ok=True)

os.chmod(local_path, 000)
```

When I checked the permissions for the `local_path`, they didn't change for that folder. If I run the same code on my physical machine, it works. Can you help me understand why?

Comment: I checked the permissions with `os.access(local_path, os.W_OK | os.X_OK)` and it returns `true`.

Comment: Despite `os.access()` the `os.chmod()` seems to be effective: Try `status = os.stat(local_path)` and then print the permission via `print("\nFile permission mask (in octal):", oct(status.st_mode)[-3:])`. The output is **000**

Comment: Is your container running as root?  I'd believe that `os.access()` call would succeed as root even if the file has permissions 000.